# P4 submit fails some times on linux with validation failed error

Tags: linux, perforce

On Linux, after a review has been completed on a CL(changelist), the

> p4 submit

fails validation indicating a file has changed after the review. Example:

```
Submit validation failed – fix problems then use 'p submit -c 123456'.
'changeContent' validation failed: This file has been changed between the time it was reviewed and the time it was committed, starting on line 2:
```

But, the file hasn't changed. This doesn't happen all the time, just some times. When it happens, it doesn't matter how many reviews get completed on the CL, it will never submit. We're forced to move the changes over to Windows and review/submit them from there. Is there any solution to it?

Comment: It sounds like you've got confusion over the line-ending conventions (CR, LF, CRLF, etc.). Probably your clients on the different operating systems aren't configured with the 'share' line ending configuration setting.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that your `changeContent` trigger is rejecting the submit.  Fixing or disabling this trigger should allow the submit to proceed.

As far as speculating about what about this trigger could be broken, Bryan's suggestion about line endings is a good one.  Maybe your Linux client is using `share` and one of your Windows clients is using `unix`?  That's a recipe for a bad time for the Linux client.

Comment: Both Windows and Linux workspaces have line endings set to: "Local: defaults to current operating system."

Comment: Could be that the trigger flat out doesn't work with Linux workspaces.  Would need to see the trigger to be able to debug it.